# How can I split a year range into year rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I split this table to:

| Year Range | Vehicle Make | Vehicle Model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2014-2018 | Nissan | GT-R |

To show as:

| Year Range | Vehicle Make | Vehicle Model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2014 | Nissan | GT-R |
| 2015 | Nissan | GT-R |
| 2016 | Nissan | GT-R |
| 2017 | Nissan | GT-R |
| 2018 | Nissan | GT-R |

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: Hints - use a tally table and split the "Year Range" column into 2 separate values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just another option using an ad-hoc tally/numbers table in concert with a CROSS APPLY

**Example**

```
Select [Year] = R1+N
      ,[Vehicle Make]
      ,[Vehicle Model]
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ( convert(int,left([Year Range] ,4))
                       ,convert(int,right([Year Range],4)) 
                      ) 
             )B(R1,R2)
 Join (Select Top 100 N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
         From  master..spt_values n1 ) C on N<=R2-R1
```

**Results**

```
Year    Vehicle Make    Vehicle Model
2014    Nissan          GT-R
2015    Nissan          GT-R
2016    Nissan          GT-R
2017    Nissan          GT-R
2018    Nissan          GT-R
```

Comment: great solution of using ad-hoc tally table. Thanks for this.

Comment: This worked beautifully for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: How did you come up with this solution John? Is there some kind of debugger in SQL Server, where you can run through a SQL script line by line? Or, did you use some website for this? I am very curious to know how you created this logic!! Thanks!!

Comment: @ASH Here is a dbFiddle which may illustrate better  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=5aade24ade51fe6e690a7177484fba77

Comment: @ASH To answer your question as to HOW .... experience and the fact that we're all standing on the shoulders of giants :)

Comment: We ARE standing on the shoulders of giants. Apparently, and ironically, Newton’s use of that phrase wasn’t even entirely of his own original thinking. Newton grabbed that phrase from someone else, who used it hundreds of years before Newton himself became associated with it. Thanks for sharing that insight!!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use recursion:

```
With MyTable as (
select YearRange='2014-2018', Make='Nissan', Model='GT-R' union all
select YearRange='2015-2020', Make='Ford', Model='Kuga'
),
AllYears as (
select ThisYear=cast(left(YearRange,4) as integer), LastYear=cast(right(YearRange,4) as integer), Make, Model from MyTable
union all
select ThisYear=ThisYear+1, LastYear=LastYear, Make, Model from AllYears where ThisYear < LastYear
)
select ThisYear, Make, Model from AllYears
order by Make, Model, ThisYear
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using recursive CTE to generate list of years and then joining the same with the table using BETWEEN clause.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(YearRange varchar(20), VehicleMake varchar(20),    VehicleModel varchar(20))

insert into @table values
('2014-2018','Nissan','GT-R');

;WITH Cte_year as
(
SELECT 2014 as y
UNION ALL
SELECT Y+1 as Y
from Cte_year
where y < 2017
), cte_rangesplit as
(
SELECT left(yearrange,4) as startRange, right(yearrange,4) as endRange
,VehicleMake, VehicleModel
from @table) 
SELECT cy.y, c.VehicleMake, c.VehicleModel FROM Cte_year as cy
inner join cte_rangesplit as c
on cy.y between c.startRange and c.endRange
```

| y | VehicleMake | VehicleModel |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2014 | Nissan | GT-R |
| 2015 | Nissan | GT-R |
| 2016 | Nissan | GT-R |
| 2017 | Nissan | GT-R |